# How can I adjust the .init event for TinyMCE in EpiServer 8.0?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, episerver

We need to get to the .init event for TinyMCE in the CMS to be able to adjust some of the settings.  How can we do this?  Here is an example of something we'd like to be able to perform.

```
tinymce.init({
    some_property : 'do something'
});
```

This is so we can adjust content filtering in TinyMCE.  My understanding is that this version of EpiServer uses TinyMCE 3.9.3. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your custom JavaScript execute whenever the CMS UI is loaded by adding something like the following to your `module.config` file in the site root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<module>
  <clientResources>
    <add name="tinymce.custominit" path="/Path/To/Script/YourScriptFile.js" resourceType="Script" />
  </clientResources>

  <clientModule>
    <moduleDependencies>
      <add dependency="CMS" type="RunAfter" />
    </moduleDependencies>
    <requiredResources>
      <add name="tinymce.custominit" />
    </requiredResources>
  </clientModule>

</module>
```

In `YourScriptFile.js` you can put whatever script you need to wire up TinyMCE events.

Your other option would be to create a plugin for TinyMCE, to allow your custom initialization code to be enabled/disabled for different Episerver properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section about creating an implementation of IDynamicConfigurationOptions in the [EPiServer documentation](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/9/Editing/Customizing-the-TinyMCE-editor) specific for TinyMCE. You have to create a class that implements IDynamicConfigurationOptions and in the GetConfigurationOptions() method you can return your data in the dictionary.